# Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\module_name\DOMDocument' not found

Tags: forms, 8

> Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\module_name\DOMDocument' not found in
>   /var/www/drupal/modules/module_name/src/form_xml.php on line 359

Any idea why Drupal cannot find DOMDocument class?

I want to execute a code when a form is submitted

```
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Find out what was submitted.
    $form_field = $form_state->getValue('content_types');

    foreach ($form_field as $key => $value){    
      if (!empty($value)){  
        $return = File::generate(); 
      }
    }
  }
```

In case you are wondering, module_name is the name of my custom module.

File::generate() is a static method which contains the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class

**The code works fine when I use [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) to execute it**, so any idea why can't it find the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class on form submit?

Seems to me as if the form blocks access to the DOMDocument class.

Comment: Did you check namespace?

Comment: Because you're not referring to it properly - needs to be `\DOMDocument` with the leading slash, or php will look in the current namespace

Comment: @Clive thanks for the suggestion, I tried changing it to `$xml = new \DOMDocument();` but no luck.

Comment: Is that definitely what's on line 359? If you add another empty line above that one, does the line in the error message change to 360? And did the error message change when you added the slash?

Comment: @Clive it is, as the [evidence](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sBFgA.jpg) shows, and it's the only DOMDocument in my code, so it has to be it. This is mind boggling.

Comment: The error message definitely didn't change at all when you added the slash? Not to `Fatal error: Class \DOMDocument' not found`?

Comment: @Clive, ugh... thanks, unpon further inspection the message did change to something else, since for testing I had remove the method call and pasted the entire code in there instead. After reverting back to the method call it works now. Feel free to add the `\DOMDocument`  as a formal answer if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename the form class file CamelCase and make a namespace declaration at the top. The namespace will be `Drupal\module_name\Form`. Place the form class file in directory module_name/src/Form/.